# Android , SQLite find the first empty row

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I find the first **insertable** `rowid` of `SQLite`?

As you know if you delete the last row (for example rowId = 10), and insert a record again, it will get the next id (rowId = 11).

So I'm not looking for the last rowId that is inserted or it's next one,just first insertable one.Thanks.

Comment: Why are you concerned about that?

Comment: because I have some related tables that when I want insert a record, I must know the other table's first insertable id for using in current table and after inserting that, I should insert my record in second table.complex :)

Comment: Just insert your new record. Then get its id (using the `Max` function) and use that id to insert a new record into the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your rowid uses the `AUTOINCREMENT` algorithm, you can query its current value from the `sqlite_sequence` table. The next id is then +1 that.

For example:

```
SELECT seq+1 FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE name='your_table_name';
```

If your rowid is a regular `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, then the rowid will be just MAX+1:

```
SELECT MAX(rowid)+1 FROM your_table_name;
```

Comment: This won't fill in gaps, e.g. someone's deleted the second row.

Comment: Why would anyone want to reuse identifiers?

Comment: If it's being used as a primary key exposed outside of the database.  The "first insertable rowid" could be as a result of deleting an earlier row.

Comment: Yes and why would anyone want to reuse it, especially if the id is exposed externally?